# How to add browser/session history to this website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a simple website which pulls a random meme using an API.

I am trying to make it so that when the user clicks the "back" button on their browser, they will see the last meme and so on.

At the moment, on each page refresh, a new meme is pulled. How can I add history to this website?

Here is the code for the JS:

```
fetch("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.title);

    if (data.nsfw) {
      location.reload();
    } else {
      let UIdiv = document.getElementById("root");
      let UIh2 = document.querySelector("h2");

      UIh2.innerText = data.title;

      let UIimg = document.createElement("img");

      UIimg.style.maxWidth = "500px";
      UIimg.style.display = "block";
      UIimg.style.marginLeft = "auto";
      UIimg.style.marginRight = "auto";

      UIimg.src = data.url;

      UIdiv.appendChild(UIimg);
    }
  })

  .catch((error) => {
    let UIheader = document.querySelector("h1");
    UIheader.innerText("An error occurred, please refresh the page!");
  });
```

Comment: You have many options in your case. One option is to store the previous image url in a global variable and subscribe to the back button event. Another option would be to make use of Local- or SessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your HTML page the followin button

```
<input type=button value='Back' onclick='window.history.go(-1); return false;'>
```

or make it as a link like:

```
<a href="www.mypage.com" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">Back </a>
```